# Is there a version of the second fundamental theorem of calculus for measurable functions in $L^p$?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Is the mapping from $L^2[0,1] \to L^2[0,1]$ by $T(f(x))= \int_a^xf(y)dy, f\in L^2[0,1]$ a continuous map? If f is just a Riemann integrable, we know the answer is yes by the 2nd fundamental theorem of calculus, but is there something similar for measurable functions/ Lebesgue integrable functions?

Comment: $|Tf(x)|\leq (\int_0^{x} |f(t)|^{2}dt)^{1/2}$ so $T$ is continuous with $\|T\| \leq1 $

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hi kavi. How should we show that map maps to a L2 function? We need to show the square of the integral of |∫f(y)dy| is finite which looks messy since that is already a integral and we need to do another integral.

Comment: If a function is bounded by a constant $C$ then it is in $L^{2}$. Take the constant as $(\int_0^{1}|f(t)|^{2}dt)^{1/2}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you for the hints. This makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have seen some commentators on other forums claim the image of T(f) is a continuous function. That is true for Riemann integrable functions by the fundamental theorem, but if f is just Lebesgue integrable on L2, why does T(f) turn that function continuous?